# Good library for Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, javascript

In my project I need to use the [Google Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) API to place users on the map.
Are there any libraries to enhance the user experience working with Google Maps?

I already noticed [Flutster](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fluster/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do try http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library/

Answer (score 2):

You could also try [jmaps](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jmaps).